# Q: Speed of car with sound

Tags: calculus

I've got this task:

A traffic policeman standing on the highway notices a change in tone of exactly one major third (f2/f1 = 4/5).

What speed can he infer?
Speed of sound c = 340 m/s

I've got this attempt:
340 m/s *(1+√5/4) = 765m/S = 2754 km/h

Can someone tell me if this is correct or if I'm completely wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Since your result for the speed of the vehicle is supersonic, that probably can't be correct.  If the vehicle is approaching the officer, who is stationary, its velocity $ \ v \ $ would be given by $$ \frac54 \ = \ \frac{c}{c-v} \ \ $$ ; if it is moving away, you would use $$ \frac45 \ = \  \frac{c}{c+v} \ \ .  $$

Comment: @boojum you get two different answers from your two equations. Perhaps $\frac45=\frac{c-v}{c+v}?$ That will give you $9v=c$, so $v=\frac c9=\frac{1235}9\frac{km}h=137.22\frac{km}h=85.22\frac{miles}h$ which seems a reasonable speeding up speed.

Comment: The $ \ v \ $ in the numerator of your expression is for the speed of the _observer_; you said the police officer is standing still, so that will be zero. And yes, the speed for the approaching vehicle will be different from that for a vehicle moving away from the observer.